# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS CURL post image file, C language

Tags: c, image, post, curl

Wonder if anyone has any experience posting image files with CURL in C..?

I am writing a program to post to a facebook Type web service, and everything is going fine, except when I attempt to post image files...

There's a special format that the server needs or it will not accept the post...

something like this:

---webformkitXXXXXXXX\r\n
filename"somefile.jpg"\r\n

JPEG or IMAGE FILE HERE (in binary)

---webformkitXXXXXXXX\r\n
END----

So when I am finally able to to memcpy together the different pieces I need,
I can save it to file, and it looks just fine, but I can see from the packet captures, that CURL doesn't like taking the binary, it appears that it's truncating the buffer at the first sign of a '\0' because, it only sends like 300 bytes, when it should be sending 80K...

I've been using this: curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CURLOPT_WRITEDATA and plug in a function you have written to write the POST data.

Comment: "You need to use CURLOPT_WRITEDATA and plug in a function you have written to write the POST data."                                                                                                                                  Are you sure...? According to the curl documentation...         "Data pointer to pass to the file write function"

Comment: So far, according to the packet captures, the closest thing was "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS" but as I mentioned, it only sends data up until it hits some binary, then craps out.... Juts FYI, I tried "CURLOPT_WRITEDATA", first as writing a callback, for it to read the data from my buffer, then as passing it a data buffer directly and finally "CURLOPT_READFUNCTION" which looks like you what you meant to say... "This function gets called by libcurl as soon as it needs to read data in order to send it to the peer" (which is what I am trying to do, send a post buffer to a peer...  Anyway, Thank you...

Comment: This looks like what I need....                                                                                                            "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE"

If you want to post data to the server without letting libcurl do a strlen() to measure the data size, this option must be used. When this option is used you can post fully binary data, which otherwise is likely to fail. If this size is set to -1, the library will use strlen() to get the size.

Comment: Just FYI, if anyone ever needs to upload a file, that is sandwiched between, "Boundary" Tokens.... Curl will generate the correct headers / tokens, all you need to use is:                           struct curl_forms forms[2];
    forms[0].option = CURLFORM_FILE;
    forms[0].value  = filename;
    forms[1].option = CURLFORM_END;curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name_of_your_image_identifier", CURLFORM_ARRAY, forms, CURLFORM_END); 
      curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name_of_the_token", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, tokenvalue,  CURLFORM_END);